# Netlogo slow to get table value from indexed turtle

Tags: performance, netlogo

I am building a Netlogo model that includes a social diffusion component, and am running into a surprising performance issue using the Table extension.

For some context: in the model, each agent has a table of attitudes with a string key (e.g. "Environment") and a float value of -1 to 1. Each tick, agents update their attitude based on those of their contacts and a weight for each contact. To prototype I'm using the simple update rule for each contact:

`a(t) = a(t-1) + w * [b(t-1) - a(t-1)]`

Where a is the agent's attitude, b is the contact attitude, and w is the weight. Each agent has 5-10 contacts.

I have implemented this in two ways. The first uses links which performs decently. However, the memory footprint for this appears to get quite large as I scale up. Since the network is not dynamic, I am experimenting with implementing this as a table where keys are contact turtle IDs and values are weights (Strictly speaking, I create a list of turtle ids called "contacts" and a table of corresponding weights to avoid recreating the list each time I iterate). This appears to use *much* less memory with many agents but is unexpectedly an order of magnitude slower.

Here is a snippet of the network-based update:

```
ask my-in-links [
   let neighborAttitude table:get [attitudes] of other-end "Environment"
   let myAttitude table:get [attitudes] of myself "Environment"
   let influence weight * (neighborAttitude - myAttitude)
   set myAttitude myAttitude + influence
   table:put [attitudes] of myself "Environment" myAttitude
  ]
```

And the table-based version:

```
  foreach (contacts) [ i ->
    let myAttitude table:get attitudes "Environment"
    let neighborAttitude table:get [attitudes] of homeowner i "Environment"
    let w table:get contactWeights i
    let influence w * (neighborAttitude - myAttitude)
    set myAttitude myAttitude + influence
    table:put attitudes "Environment" myAttitude
  ]
```

From some testing it appears the big slowdown occurs from getting the neighborAttitude. If I comment out that line, getting and putting from the agent's attitude table seems just as fast as the network based block. So it seems to be finding the other turtle ("homeowner").

Is there something inherently really slow in NetLogo of looking up a turtle/agent by id? This seems like it should be basically free but I don't know what the data structure is for this under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

This code is very not-NetLogo like so I am having some trouble parsing it and my comment/answer may have completely missed the point.

I don't understand the use of `table` at all for these lines:

```
ask my-in-links [
   let neighborAttitude table:get [attitudes] of other-end "Environment"
```

You are starting with `ask my-in-links`. Presumably this is inside an `ask turtles` or similar block. So running the code first chooses a turtle, let's say that turtle has 5 links to other turtles. It hits this code and runs through each of those 5 links and creates a table with those 5 values that are somehow stored in a table with the key `[attitudes] of other-end "Environment"`.

Assuming you have links (which you must to be able to use `ask my-in-links`) then a much more NetLogo-ish way of doing this is something like the following. Note that this is a full model, you can put it in an empty NetLogo model to run it.

```
turtles-own
[ myAttitude
  myUpdatedAttitude
]

links-own
[ wgt
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set myAttitude -1 + random-float 2
  ]
  ; create a network
  repeat 50
  [ ask one-of turtles
    [ create-link-to one-of other turtles
      [ set wgt random-float 1 ]
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  type "average attitude: " print mean [myAttitude] of turtles
  let w 0.4
  ; calculate next value and store until all calculated
  ask turtles with [any? in-link-neighbors]
  [ let wtd-diffs [([myAttitude] of other-end - [myAttitude] of myself) * wgt] of my-in-links
    set myUpdatedAttitude (1 - w) * myAttitude + w * sum wtd-diffs 
  ]
  ; make the change
  ask turtles [ set myAttitude myUpdatedAttitude ]
  tick
end
```

For each turtle in turn, this code constructs a list of the weighted difference in attitude values between the turtle and the turtles it is influenced by. So, if it has 5 `in-link-neighbors`, the wtd-diffs list will have 5 values. The next line calculates the total influence, storing it in a different value so all the calculations are done on the current value. Note that I haven't used exactly your equation as I wasn't sure how you were keeping it from simply growing uncontrollably.

I realise this doesn't answer your question about table performance, but I expect this approach will solve all your performance issues.

Comment: Thanks, @JenB. I'm realizing that my example code was perhaps more complicated than necessary as the use of the table extension to store attitudes was extraneous.

To clarify, the block is not _creating_ a table to store values. With the table extension, the syntax `table:get <table> <key> of <turtle>` references the value of a table for a given turtle. Equivalent would be `let neighborAttitude [...] of other-end`. The solution is also slightly different here, since I have a weight for each contact which can be between 0 and 1. I could use your approach with map reduce.

Comment: A simplified example below without tables. This yields something different (I'm pretty sure) from an average of differences (apologies, forgot limitation of comments!):

  ask my-in-links [
   let myAttitude [environment] of myself
   let influence weight * ([environment] of other-end - myAttitude)
   set [environment] of myself myAttitude + influence
  ]

Comment: I still don't understand the use of tables at all. A different weight for each contact is straightforward by making the weight an attribute of the link, will amend. You have a link for each contact, what is the table actually storing?

Comment: Yes, the influence weight is an attribute of the links. The table is used to store the attitudes. There happen to be several, where the label (e.g. "environment") is the key and the value is the attitude. They could each be separate attributes and the problem would persist, since the actual issue (see my own answer) appears to be with the cost of the line `let someVariable [attribute] of turtle i` which ends up being quite slow if there are lots of turtles because it must go through each until it matches. It turns out to be quite fast if I make a table of all turtles with their id as the key.

Comment: I changed my code to have 20000 agents with 10 inflences each. Each iteration of all 20000 turtles takes about 20 seconds. What performance are you expecting?

Comment: I think I narrowed things down even more; see below; the culprit seems to be the use of the breed keyword vs `turtle i`.

Answer (score 0):

Right after submitting this I tried an experiment that confirms my suspicion, and I think resulted in an acceptable solution. It does turn out that simply asking turtles to look up "turtle i" is slow, and gets slower with an increasing number of agents.

I'm *guessing* that with `of turtle i` Netlogo is doing the equivalent of `of turtles with [who = i]` and must be iterating through a list of all turtles until it finds the matching ID. So as a test, using the table extension again I manually created a table of all turtles:

```
globals [turtleTable]
...
to initialize-turtleTable
  set turtleTabletable:make
  ask turtles [
    table:put turtleTable who self
  ]
end
```

Then instead of `of turtle i` you can say `of table:get turtleTable i`. This is slightly  more cumbersome syntax but could be cleaned up with a reporter. This ends up performing as originally expected, about on par with using links, but with around 25,000 agents uses nearly half the memory (<3GB vs >5GB), compared by completely exiting and relaunching NetLogo.

Comment: `turtle i` is an efficient constant-time lookup. Or at least it was when during the 13 years I worked on NetLogo — I can't be certain it hasn't regressed since then, but I'd be quite surprised if it has. I think you should consider other possible explanations first.

Comment: I certainly  expected that, so I have been trying to dig more into why the change I made sped things up so much here. If I had nothing in that block except `let neighborAttitude [anyVariable] of homeowner i` it absolutely tanked, while replacing it with a table lookup was over _ten times_ faster. But, just now in a greatly simplified test model that isolates this and where I can change between the two methods, they indeed seem to perform about the same. Which... is what I would expect, since glancing at the code turtle sets appear to be arrays.

Comment: Ah, @SethTisue. I found something in my test model. `turtle i` is efficient, and even somewhat faster than the table. But when I create agents as a custom breed (e.g. tunas) and then try to use `tuna i` then performance drops by about an order of magnitude. I did not expect `breed` to be different from `turtle`. Any reason for that?

Comment: To confirm: the lookup time for breed, i.e. `of tuna i` increases with the index. I create 1,000 turtles of breed tuna, and each tick reset the timer and ask each turtle `let j [someVariable] of tuna i` where _i_ starts at zero and increments. I plot the timer. The lookup time for tuna 0 is around zero but goes up at least linearly. `... of turtle i` shows constant time as expected.

Comment: please report the problem at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues — if that holds up it's a serious regression

Comment: @SethTisue Just submitted a report along with a test program and screenshots, we'll see if its replicable or if I'm somehow doing something wrong: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1856

Comment: Excellent — thanks for working to isolate this. I won't be able to respond to the report myself as I no longer work on NetLogo directly, but I think the current development team will take an interest.